# Categories for each brands

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I have searched for hours but could not find an answer to this, or a module to help.

We are building a store and our client needs the ability to navigate the store by manufacturer. Is there any way that the manufacturer page can list the categories and subcategories.

There seems two ways to do it.

Add brands while adding categories in admin section.
Get all categories inside the brands by join operation while viewing the manufacturer.
Are there any modules available to link up categories with manufacturers so that I can display categories inside the manufacturer page.

Or the only way is to query all the products inside the manufacturer and get the categories out of it... I guess it is not a good solution.

So any suggestions would be a great help.

Thanks.

Comment: I can recommend Woocommerce's Brands plugin: https://woocommerce.com/products/brands/